# How do I generate the emission sources for calpuff (SRC)?

Tags: emissions

I have compiled Calpuff and mmif, hence Calmet it is not necessary because I create the Calmet output from WRF using mmif. Now I only need to create the emission inputs files. According to calpuff.inp, the emission inputs files are:

```
Emission Files
PTEMARB.DAT input * PTDAT   = *
VOLEMARB.DAT input * VOLDAT = *
BAEMARB.DAT input * ARDAT   = *
LNEMARB.DAT input * LNDAT   = *
```

How do I generate this files? 
I've navigated into the calpuff.for file but I still cant find the proper Fortran format.

Thanks